# get all students who has got more marks than the average marks of that class

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got two tables below called `tbl_student` where we store students' data like id, name, class, roll no. and age, and `tbl_marks` where we store marks scored in an exam. -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tbl_student
(
    student_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    student_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    student_class integer,
    student_roll_no integer,
    age integer,
    CONSTRAINT tbl_student_pkey PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tbl_marks
(
    marks_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    student_id integer NOT NULL,
    subject varchar(255),
    marks integer,
    CONSTRAINT tbl_marks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (marks_id)
)
```

And these are some data for the respective tables:

```
INSERT INTO
    public.tbl_student (student_name, student_class, student_roll_no, age)
VALUES
    ('John Doe',5,1, 12),
    ('Clark Keny', 5,2, 10),
    ('Ross Barkley', 5, 3, 11),
    ('Frank Lampard', 5, 4, 9),
    ('John Terry', 5, 5, 10),
    ('Peter Parker',6,1, 13),
    ('Tony Stark', 6,2,11),
    ('Bruce Wayne', 6, 3,14),
    ('Johnny Depp', 6, 4,11),
    ('Jackie Chan',7,1,15),
    ('John Wick', 7,2,14),
    ('Indiana Jones', 7, 3,11),
    ('Halley Berry', 7, 4,12),
    ('Jane Doe', 7, 5,15),
    ('Martha Kent', 7, 6,13);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO
    public.tbl_marks (student_id, subject, marks)
VALUES
    (1, 'Math' , 79),
    (1, 'Science' , 64),
    (2, 'Math' , 69),
    (2, 'Science' , 72),
    (3, 'Math' , 30),
    (3, 'Science' , 50),
    (4, 'Math' , 77),
    (4, 'Science' , 72),
    (5, 'Math' , 84),
    (5, 'Science' , 88),
    (6, 'Math' , 36),
    (6, 'Science' , 54),
    (7, 'Math' , 55),
    (7, 'Science' , 54),
    (8, 'Math' , 66),
    (8, 'Science' , 78),
    (9, 'Math' , 43),
    (9, 'Science' , 20),
    (10, 'Math' ,87 ),
    (10, 'Science' , 92),
    (11, 'Math' , 68),
    (11, 'Science' , 82),
    (12, 'Math' , 78),
    (12, 'Science' , 93),
    (13, 'Math' , 20),
    (13, 'Science' , 22),
    (14, 'Math' , 40),
    (14, 'Science' , 42),
    (15, 'Math' , 52),
    (15, 'Science' , 62);
```

Now, I need to get all students in each class who got more marks than the average marks in their respective classes.

I tried it using the `RANK()` function with the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.  Your first step is to get the averages.  Then you use that as a nested query to fetch the above average.  The bigger problem is that there are no A students in math in this school.  ;)

Comment: Hey @TimRoberts, yes that is how I think it should work. What I tried is not very close to the solution. I have only a little knowledge about SQLs but need to get it done soon. Sorry about the bad math teacher at the school.

Comment: @Suday In "tbl_student" can you also add student_id column values . Because two students can have the same roll but exist in different class. So to distinguish students we need student_id column value in tbl_student table

Comment: @ShuchitaRahamn student_id is there on both tables. For tbl_student, its auto-generated, that's why I didn't add on insertion query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM
     ( SELECT s.*
            , m.subject
            , m.marks
            , avg(m.marks) OVER (PARTITION BY m.subject, s.student_class) AS marks_avg
         FROM tbl_marks AS m
        INNER JOIN tbl_student AS s
           ON s.student_id = m.student_id
    ) AS a
WHERE a.marks > a.marks_avg
```

see the result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a14eb2349bc9d5acdfc6b06d75846c47).

see the manual about the window functions :

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WINDOW
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html

and also about the aggregate functions which can be used as window functions :

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: Clearly I need to learn about OVER and PARTITION BY.  Those were not part of SQL when I learned it.

Comment: Hey @Edouard, thanks for this. I didn't know we can PARTITION BY multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so finding the averages is like this:

```
    SELECT s.student_class, m.subject, AVG(m.marks) AS average
      FROM tbl_marks m INNER JOIN tbl_student s USING (student_id) 
      GROUP by s.student_class, m.subject
```

So, we just need to use that as another table in the join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.student_name, s.student_class, m.subject, m.marks
  FROM tbl_marks m 
  INNER JOIN tbl_student s USING (student_id) 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s.student_class, m.subject, AVG(m.marks) AS average
      FROM tbl_marks m INNER JOIN tbl_student s USING (student_id) 
      GROUP by s.student_class, m.subject) x1 
    USING (student_class, subject)
  WHERE m.marks >= x1.average;
```

Output:

```
John Doe              5              Math        79        
Clark Keny            5              Math        69        
Clark Keny            5              Science     72        
Frank Lampard         5              Math        77        
Frank Lampard         5              Science     72        
John Terry            5              Math        84        
John Terry            5              Science     88        
Peter Parker          6              Science     54        
Tony Stark            6              Math        55        
Tony Stark            6              Science     54        
Bruce Wayne           6              Math        66        
Bruce Wayne           6              Science     78        
Jackie Chan           7              Math        87        
Jackie Chan           7              Science     92        
John Wick             7              Math        68        
John Wick             7              Science     82        
Indiana Jones         7              Math        78        
Indiana Jones         7              Science     93
```